# eigenvalues and their analogy with frequency

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I was reading [this document](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf). At page 25, paragraph 2, there was mention of eigenvalues (and frequency; degree of freedom) of a kernel matrix. I am attaching the corresponding image for reader's convenience:

[image]

Please explain me the analogy or the correspondence of eigenvalues of a kernel(covariance) matrix with frequency and the concept of smoothing.

Comment: In context the remark is about kernels used "in practice" which means you would need an example to get a clean mathematical explanation.

Comment: Could you please explain for the case of radial basis function kernel (as used in the document)